# Probability distribution of probabilities

Tags: classification, logistic-regression, binary-classification

We can get the prediction probabilities of a binary classifier from sklearn's API using the predict_proba method. Is it reasonable to expect that the shape of a histogram plotted for the prediction probabilities of let's say the '1' class to approximate a normal distribution? What is the statistical theory that allows for this? I noticed this instance for a logistic regression model I trained.

Comment: I think it is better if you ask this question on https://stats.stackexchange.com/. Datascience exchange is for DS related things, while stats is for statistics related. Your question seems more to be statistics related.

Answer (score 1):

The landscape of the output probabilities depends entirely on the training data. If the data itself is sampled from a normal distribution, then the learned probabilities will reflect that. Otherwise, no.

Therefore, in the general case, no, it is not reasonable to expect the shape of a histogram plotted from the prediction probabilities to approximate a normal distribution.

Comment: Thanks for you feedback @noe, and your observation makes sense. That said, I did find a similar case under stack exchange-crossvalidated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/576151/binary-classification-problem-with-predicted-probabilities-distribution-skewed. It suggests that the better the classifier performs the more skewed one should expect the distribution to be. Do you agree? I know you noted that if the data was sampled from a normal distribution, the probabilities should reflect that. Does  this assertion go against what the link suggests?

Comment: I think that in the linked question they used the term "normal" as in "usual", referring to the close match between predictions and true values; I don't think they refer to the Gaussian distribution.

Comment: Also, the skewness of the distribution of predicted probabilities can be very high (the model is "very sure") and yet the accuracy be very low.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning the beta distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution), as a specific distribution over probabilities that naturally describes both the certain and uncertain regimes for classifiers.